# How do I get the value of a barcode with a barcode reader from my viewmodel without needing a textbox? wpf c #

Tags: c#, wpf, viewmodel, barcode

I want to obtain the barcode returned by a barcode reader without the need for the focus to be in a textbox, which only needs to be open one view.

For now what I'm doing is this in my Vista

```
<UserControl x:Class="Capa_Presentacion_WPF.Views.AutoServicio.AutoServicio"
             xmlns:local="clr-namespace:Capa_Presentacion_WPF.Views.AutoServicio"
             xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
             xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
             xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
             xmlns:materialDesign="http://materialdesigninxaml.net/winfx/xaml/themes"
             xmlns:i="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/2010/interactivity"
             xmlns:local11="clr-namespace:Capa_Entidades.Models;assembly=Capa_Entidades"
             mc:Ignorable="d"            
             d:DesignHeight="768" d:DesignWidth="1130" Background="Lavender"
             Loaded="UserControl_Loaded"
             KeyDown="UserControl_KeyDown">
    <UserControl.InputBindings>
        <KeyBinding Command="{Binding Path=EnterCommand}" Key="Enter"/>
        <KeyBinding Command="{Binding Path=KeyF1Command}" Key="F1" />
        <KeyBinding Command="{Binding Path=KeyF2Command}" Key="F2" />
        <KeyBinding Command="{Binding Path=KeyF3Command}" Key="F3" />
        <KeyBinding Command="{Binding Path=KeyF4Command}" Key="F4" />
        <KeyBinding Command="{Binding Path=KeyF12Command}" Key="F12" />
    </UserControl.InputBindings>
</UserControl>
```

The first ** <KeyBinding ** refers to me when it detects the "enter", since the codes that are read with the reader come with an enter to the last one. I was thinking of using that, but the problem there is how do I get the code before the "enter"?

The other thing that this is is that I program in a textbox, but that's what I don't want, I just want to get the code and to execute a function when reading the barcode, without having to be in a textbox or any other control.

Currently I associate it to my textbox as follows:

```
<TextBox Background="White" Margin="0,0,10,10" Name="textBoxBuscador"
                     Text="{Binding Buscador, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" MaxLines="1" Focusable="True">
                <TextBox.InputBindings>
                    <KeyBinding Command="{Binding Path=BindKeyCommand}" Key="Enter" />
                    <KeyBinding Command="{Binding Path=KeyF1Command}" Key="F1" />
                    <KeyBinding Command="{Binding Path=KeyF2Command}" Key="F2" />
                    <KeyBinding Command="{Binding Path=KeyF3Command}" Key="F3" />
                    <KeyBinding Command="{Binding Path=KeyF4Command}" Key="F4" />
                    <KeyBinding Command="{Binding Path=KeyF12Command}" Key="F12" />
                </TextBox.InputBindings>
                <TextBox.Style>
                    <Style>
                        <Style.Triggers>
                            <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding SomeTextIsFocused, 
                                Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" Value="True">
                                <Setter Property="FocusManager.FocusedElement" 
                                        Value="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}}" />
                            </DataTrigger>
                        </Style.Triggers>
                    </Style>
                </TextBox.Style>
                <i:Interaction.Behaviors>
                    <local11:FocusChangedBehavior IsFocused="{Binding SomeTextIsFocused}" />
                </i:Interaction.Behaviors>
            </TextBox>
```

I bind a string object called **Buscador**, and inside the <Binding it is calling a command when pressing the "enter" key that is in my viewmodel

This is my ViewModel:

```
private void Enter()
        {
            try
            {
                int c = this.DataPlatosBusqueda.Where(p => p.cbarplato.Contains(Buscador.ToUpper())).Count();
                if (c > 0)
                {
                    var id = this.DataPlatosBusqueda.Where(p => p.cbarplato.Contains(Buscador.ToUpper())).FirstOrDefault().idplato.ToString();
                    if (id != null)
                    {
                        PasarPlatos(id);
                        SomeTextIsFocused = true;
                    }
                    this.Buscador = "";
                    SomeTextIsFocused = true;
                }
                this.Buscador = "";
                SomeTextIsFocused = true;
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                globales.Mensaje("Error:", "Opcion Enter: " + ex.Message.ToString(), 3);
            }
            
        }
```

Comment: Make a simple google search, and you can start from there.

Comment: Since we know nothing about your barcode reader or how it works, and we cannot see the code you've got now to read the code, it's really difficult to help. Please provide more information. See [How To Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) for more guidance. Thanks.

Comment: Edit my question, thanks

Comment: What barcode reader are you using?

Comment: It's still unclear how the barcode reader is associated with this textbox. Is this usercontrol a component supplied by the barcode manufacturer? Or did you create it?

Comment: I am using a linear barcode reader, what I want is to be able to read the code and get it in my viewmodel, without having to have a textbox or press a button, just by simply reading the barcode, execute an action, for example a MessageBox

Comment: Yes you already said that. It would be more useful if you could answer my specific question, instead of repeating your original point. If you don't understand my question, please say that.

Comment: yes, i create usercontrol

Comment: ok so then please show us the code for how you associate the barcode reader with the textbox.

Comment: Done, it's edited

Comment: `this.DataPlatosBusqueda` is a database object I guess? if not, what is it? I still don't see how that has anything to do with the barcode reader. What code is it which says "when the barcode reader scans a code, put that code into the textbox". That's what we're interested in. Is `this.DataPlatosBusqueda` related to your barcode reader somehow? Bear in mind that your variable names are not in English, and so their meaning will not be obvious to most people reading here.

Answer (score 1):

Broadly speaking, barcode readers fall into two groups.

There are those that are intended for remote stocktaking and the like. These have internal memory and often store data internally for later download. They can often send the data via wi fi to a url. Essentially posting got one of these. Got one of these... as you scan.

The other category is purely an input device like a keyboard. And like a keyboard, you need something to take that input. The simplest approach is a textbox but you can also handle key input at say a window level if that has focus.

A window level key handler would look something like:

```
    private void Window_KeyHandler(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
    {
        var keypressed = e.Key;
        // do something with keypressed
    }
```

And you can hook it in a window:

```
this.PreviewKeyDown += new KeyEventHandler(Window_KeyHandler);
```

There is also a previewtextinput event.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.uielement.previewtextinput?view=netcore-3.1

There are a number of potential issues you could hit with this implementation. One of which being mis reads where it doesn't read the data right and drops a number, reads it as a different one or some such.

Which is why it is usual to simply have a textbox and take the input there.
If the scanner you have is a regular cheap to mid range one then I recommend you reconsider your approach.
This is how apps I've worked on do this and it's useful even when someone is scanning many items very quickly as they come off a conveyor.

If this is an expensive scanner than you could well have the option to post your data direct to a url.  You could build a simple web api site and take input there. Your view and wpf app would then be more about seeing what had been input.

Comment: Hello, thanks for your answer, I could do it with a text box, but my problem is that if the user removes the focus from this text box and goes to another, etc. You may think that the system is failing or you may have problems when trying to read the codes, since this system is made for a market that passes its products through the reader.

Comment: The warehouse and despatch systems i worked on had extremely simple views. There was only one control could take focus in the view where warehouse staff would be scanning. If the view was open, it would have focus on the textbox and take scanned input.

Comment: With some USB barcode readers it's also possible to switch the mode from keyboard emulation to 'HID' mode which enables you to connect to the device directly and read the data as a stream or subscribe events. Some also have their own properierty API and communication protocol which lets you do the same. Cheaper models only have Keyboard emulation, and using this answer will give you the result you need without using a textbox.